# To what extent is the taylor polynomial the best polynomial approximation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Given a function $f\in\mathscr C^n([a,b])$ and a point $x_0\in [a,b]$, to what extent is the n-th taylor polynomial $T_n(x,x_0)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(x_0)}{k!}(x-x_0)^k$ the best polynomial approximation of $f$ in $[a,b]$ ? This may seem to be dumb question, but is there a metric $\rho$ on $ C^n([a,b])$ so that $\rho(T_n(x,x_0),f)=\min\{\rho(p,f)\mid \text{p is a polynomial function} \}$ ? 
Thank you

Comment: Interesting question! One things to remark is that the Taylor polynomial is definitely *not* the best approximation in the sup norm on $\mathcal C[a,b]$. This was studied by Tchebychev, who showed that for each $n$, there is a best such approximation of degree $n$. It is usually significantly more accurate than the Taylor polynomial. See for example Chapters 43-45 (especially 44) of Körner's "Fourier analysis".

Answer (score 15):

Here is a norm on $\mathscr C^n(a,b)$ for which $T_{n}(\cdot,x_0)$  is the best approximation to $f$: 
$$\|f\|_* = \sum_{k=0}^{n} |f^{(k)}(x_0)|+ \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(x_0)|$$
This is a reasonable norm, which is equivalent to the more usual norms. For any polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$ we have 
$$\|f-p\|_* = \sum_{k=0}^{n} |f^{(k)}(x_0)-p^{(k)}(x_0)|+ \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f^{(n)}(x)-f^{(n)}(x_0)|$$
which is minimized exactly when $p=T_{n}(\cdot,x_0)$.

Comment: +1 This is very interesting, I had never seen such a norm. Can you provide a reference where I can find that norm defined?

Comment: @AdriánBarquero Sure. Here it is in amsrefs format:   `\bib\{298965}{misc}{    
    title={To what extent is the taylor polynomial the best polynomial approximation?},    
    author={5PM (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/53153/5pm)},    
    note={URL: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298965 (version: 2013-02-11)},    
    eprint={http://math.stackexchange.com/q/298965},    
    organization={Mathematics}  
}`  //  but seriously, I don't recall seeing it anywhere.

Comment: I see, so you came up with it? That's really clever. Thanks =)

Comment: I may be misunderstanding something here but if I set f = p in your metric the first term is zero but the second term is not zero. But isn't the norm of 0 supposed to be zero?

Comment: @MichaelSmith If $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, then $f^{(n)}$ is a constant function.

Comment: @5PM Thanks - that makes sense. I had misread the formula as f(k) with k = 0 to n. Works for f = p giving zero norm.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is that the Taylor polynomial is not a very good approximation on the whole of $[a,b]$ in general. Indeed, the rest of the Taylor series converges to 0 on $[a,b]$ if and only if $f$ is analytic, which of course is not always the case. The intuition is that local information near $x_0$ only has no chance of being sufficient for a good approximation on $[a,b]$.

We know that a continuous function can be approximated uniformly on a segment by polynomials, but it is a bit tricky to find which polynomials exactly. Another natural candidate would be interpolation polynomials, but it turns out that they are no good as well (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon). The answer is Bernstein's polynomials (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_polynomial_theorem).

Comment: The Runge phenomenon does not mean that "interpolation polynomials ... are no good". It shows the limitations of interpolation *with equidistant nodes*. Interpolation with Chebyshev nodes yields uniform approximation, and the Wikipedia article you cited mentions this.

Comment: you're right. my point was just that this is a non-trivial question, and that naive answer may be false.

Answer (score 7):

$T_n(x, x_0)$ is the only polynomial of degree less than or equal to $n$ such that

$$ T_n(x, x_0) - f(x) \in o((x - x_0)^n) $$

or in terms of limits,

$$ \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{T_n(x, x_0) - f(x)}{(x - x_0)^n} = 0$$