# Why is a Maclaurin series the function itself for a polynomial $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

It's been about two years since I last took Calc 2, and I'm trying to brush up on some of the old material using Khanacademy. I watched a couple [intro videos on the subject](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-11/v/maclaurin-and-taylor-series-intuition) and understand Taylor series at an intuitive level, without memorizing definitions.

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see what would happen if one wanted to (for some reason) approximate a function as simple as $f(x) = x^3$ using a Maclaurin series. I was wondering if I'd get something complex that roughly approximates this function and, if so, how far off I would be:

$f(x) = f'(0) + f'(0)x +  \frac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3 + \frac{f''''(0)}{4!}x^4 + 0 + 0 + ...$

Okay, so here are the derivatives:

- $f'(x) = 3x^2; f'(0) = 0$
- $f''(x) = 6x; f''(0) = 0$
- $f'''(x) = 6; f'''(0) = 6$
- $f''''(x) = 0; f''''(0) = 0$

So it becomes:

$f(x) = 0 + 0 + 0 + \frac{6x^3}{6} + 0 + ...$

And that's just $f(x) = x^3$, the original function.

**Question**: Why does this end up being an exact match and not just an inaccurate "approximation" for a simple polynomial function?

Comment: Because a polynomial is a *exact* polynomial ‘approximation’ of itself. Same reason  for a linear function is its own differential.

Comment: Oh... Wow. When you put it like that, it kinda makes this seem silly, lol. That makes sense.

Comment: Were you hoping for a better approximation?  ^_^

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298837/to-what-extent-is-the-taylor-polynomial-the-best-polynomial-approximation,

Answer (score 2):

Because, as you can check, if $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_nx^n$, then$$f^{(k)}(0)=\begin{cases}k!a_k&\text{ if }k\leqslant n\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Therefore,$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k.$$

Comment: I don't doubt that this is technically correct, but the interval notation part is a little confusing. I don't like "formal" math too much.

Comment: Exactly *what* did you find confusing?

Comment: See above, I think my edit didn't refresh on your end. The interval notation part is a little confusing for me. I understand the generic expression for $f(x)$ and recognize the last part as just the Maclaurin series.

Comment: *Specifically, I don't understand how you bridge the gap between the interval notation and the maclaurin series notation. What intuition/understanding am I missing?

Comment: @AleksandrH, what do you mean by "interval notation"?

Comment: I'm probably using the wrong terminology, sorry. I mean the "if k <= n, otherwise" part. I know what all that means, I just don't get how you derived it, or how that leads to the maclaurin series equation.

Comment: You just do the computations. You have $f(0)=a_0$, right?! And $f'(0)=a_1$, right?! And $f''(0)=2a_2$, right?! And so on, until $f^{(n)}(0)=n!a_n$. But, in fact, $f^{(n)}$ is **constant**; it is always equal to $n!a_n$. So, $f^{(k)}$ is constant and equal to $0$ if $k>n$.