# Why do smaller intervals give more accurate results?

Tags: derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I'm doing a lot of derivatives. But I'm stumped on this one question.

*Why is it that a smaller changes in x correspond to a more accurate value of the slope at that point? Or actually, ***how*** do we know that smaller changes mean give us the slope at that point?*

I have done quite a bit of calculus without really understanding this and I would appreciate it if anyone could help me understand the reasoning behind this.

Comment: It's the definition of derivative. Convergence of the limit implies smaller changes in $x$ give more accurate results.

Comment: @Chrystomath I'm sorry but I'm still in High School and I do not understand what you just said. Could you please explain it in simpler terms?

Comment: "Slope at point" is abstraction under which we understand derivative. Real slope needs 2 points. As closer they are, then more close is real slope to abstraction one.

Comment: You've seen this picture, right: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#/media/File:Derivative_GIF.gif As $h$ approaches $0$ the slope of the secant line approaches the slope of the tangent line.

Comment: Has anyone actually ever shown you a particular function and then shown how they know the smaller changes in $x$ really give slope values closer and closer to a limit? Have they used a delta-epsilon proof to show this? Have you ever even seen a delta-epsilon proof of any limit? If the answers so far have not resolved your doubts, you might get better answers if people knew more about what you know.

Comment: @DavidK do you think my question can be resolved by first understanding the epsilon-delta proofs? I haven't actually done those proofs and am wondering if understanding them will in turn resolve my question?

Comment: It might help. You might still have doubts; the delta-epsilon technique has a lot of parts that must all be understood together and I think it may be difficult to learn from a book. You might think of it as a way of enforcing the idea of the now-accepted answer with ironclad mathematical logic. If you *had* seen these proofs before then it still might be necessary to explain how they relate to that idea.

Comment: An important point mentioned in the answer below is that "how do we know" is that actually we *don't* always know, because sometimes it's not true at some point of some function, like at the sharp corner of the graph of $y=|x|$. So we have lots of proofs to make sure it actually does work for the functions where it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the graph of some function $y=f(x)$ (e.g. you could take $f(x)=x^2$ to visualise), pick two points $x_0$ and $x_0+h$ and their corresponding $y$ values. So, you have points $A=(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $B=(x_0+h,f(x_0+h))$. Now draw a line through $A$ and $B$.

Recall that the derivative of a function is essentially the gradient of its tangent line at a point. Now, if $h$ is large, the line $AB$ doesn't look like a tangent line at all. But as you shrink $h$, the line gets closer and closer to becoming a tangent line at $A$. If you don't believe me, just draw the picture yourself (or use some software like GeoGebra) and see with your own eyes.

Another way to see this: it can be shown, mathematically, that any "sufficiently nice" function $f(x)$ looks like a straight line when you zoom in enough, and this straight line is the tangent line. In other words, the tangent like to a graph at a point is usually a very good approximation to the function, near the point of tangency. I say "sufficiently nice" because some "not nice" functions like $f(x)=|x|$ don't satisfy this condition, because at $x=0$ there's a little bump. Roughly speaking, you need the function to be smooth and not have these sharp turns---this condition is known as "differentiability" and determines whether or not the derivative is defined. So, for a differentiable function, the points $A,B$ approximately lie on the same tangent line for small $h$, thus the slope of $AB$ is approximately the same as the derivative at $A$.

Answer (score 0):

To me, Taylor series gives the best explanation.

The formula is
$f(x+h)
=f(x)+hf'(x)+h^2f''(x)+...+h^nf^{(n)}(x)/n!+...
$

If we just look at the first two terms as an approximation we get

$f(x+h)
\approx f(x)+hf'(x)
$
with an error described by the next term which is proportional to
$h^2$.
This means that the smaller $h$ gets,
the more accurate the approximation is.

Answer (score 0):

A differentiable function is precisely a function where, as you say, smaller changes in $x$ correspond to a more accurate value of the slope at that point.

It is easy to produce examples of functions that are not differentiable, i.e. where smaller changes in $x$ do not produce better approximations to the slope. Any point where a function is not continuous is also a point where the function is not differentiable.

More exotically, there are functions which are continuous everywhere, but differentiable nowhere. These are known as Weierstrass functions. Roughly, the function oscillates too wildly at every point to have a well-defined slope.

Comment: Also, even if the function **is** differentiable at a point, a smaller change in $x$ **can** correspond to a less accurate value of the slope at the point. Consider $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ with $f(0) = 0.$ Note that $f'(0) = 0.$ For each $x = \frac{1}{\pi},$ $\frac{1}{2\pi},\;\ldots$ we have $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = 0 = f'(0),$ but for other values of $x$ very close to (but not equal to) any of these values of $x$ (and on the left sides, so they're closer to $0)$ the values of $\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$ are not equal to $0,$ and thus give less accurate values of the slope at $x=0.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro is there any proof that actually says smaller intervals give more accurate results for a particular function, say f(x) = 2x+3

Comment: @Sathvik R.: For most functions given by a "nice" formula, in particular a polynomial, this can be done, but the subtly of the algebra needed might be too much for you now. However, in the case of a first-degree polynomial like $2x+3,$ all the difference quotients are **equal to** the slope at any of the points, and thus I suppose in this case using smaller intervals **doesn't** give more accurate results (but you also won't get a less accurate result). Somewhat beside the point (pun intended), [this might also be of interest](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3842029/13130).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I do not want to be a bother, but what about the case of x^2? Or perhaps, is there any simple intuitive way for me to understand until I learn higher mathematics, such as using the example of velocity?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Perhaps I was a bit sloppy saying that differentiable function is precisely one where smaller intervals give more accurate values of the slope. Rather, we should say that we can get as accurate a value for the slope as we want by making the interval smaller. In any case, that's an interesting counterexample to keep in mind to avoid exactly this kind of confusion.

Comment: @Sathvik R.: I think your specific concern is possibly due to the distinction between ensuring any specified accuracy and having the accuracy **always** get better. Think about a winding path through one-way streets in a city trying to get to a certain destination. Given any specified distance from the destination, there will be a point in the drive at which you'll be within that specified distance **and stay within that specified distance**, but that point might not be the first time you're within that specified distance because maybe a one-way street goes somewhat close to it **(continued)**

Comment: but you need to follow that one-way street down a bit to obtain access to another one-way street going the other way that will take you right to the destination. Also, the fact that you can always ensure any specified accuracy (and remain within this level of accuracy) comes straight out of the definition of a limit, and has nothing specific to do with derivatives and such (other than the fact that the derivative is defined as a limit, but many other things in math are also defined as a limit).