# Can I view the Taylor polynomial as a generalization of the derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

We know that we can regard a derivative as the "best linear approximation" of a function $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ at a given point $x_0 \in (a,b)$. I was wondering whether we can view the Taylor polynomial as "the best polynomial approximation".

Another person has already asked [a quite similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298837/to-what-extent-is-the-taylor-polynomial-the-best-polynomial-approximation), but I am not very satisfied with the answer because the norm that was defined in the first answer seems a bit arbitrary. I would suggest to define a Taylor polynomial in the following way:

> Let $f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function. A $k$-th order polynomial $p_k$ is a Taylor polynomial of order $k$ of $f$ at $x_0 \in (a,b)$, if there exists a function $r_k: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$ f(x) = p_k (x) + r_k (x) \quad \text{ with } \quad \lim\limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{r_k(x)}{(x-x_0)^k} = 0.$$

I already know that if  $f$ is $k$ times differentiable at $x_0$, then this definition coincides with the usual one. My question is: Is it necessary for $f$ to be differentiable $k$ times at $x_0$? If not, does it have major implications on things like uniqueness, etc?

Comment: You can generally express various problems in equivalent ways. One looks more global, constructing a norm such that the minimizer results in the Taylor expansion. Yours is a local limiting condition, which is ultimately saying the same thing. Without $k$ derivatives it's approximately meaningless to take a Taylor approximation at order $k$. Take the extreme of $k=0$. What good is it to approximate a *discontinuous* function by any value in the first place?

Comment: It should be  "$\!f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)\,$ is the best linear approximation" instead. The derivative itself is $\,f'(x_0).$

Comment: It seems so, these can also be seen as generalized derivatives just like functional limits, ie nonlinear.

Comment: there's no issue of uniqueness; it's fairly standard to prove that if two polynomials are equal up to order $k$ (i.e that quotient has limit zero) at $x_0$ then they are infact identical. And no, for $k\geq 2$, it is possible to have such an approximating polynomial, yet the function not be $k$-times differentiable at $x_0$.

Comment: The trivial issue is that $f$ isn't even guaranteed continuous at $x_0$ if a Taylor polynomial exists. But fixing that, I'm not sure if this is true, because to talk about ie second derivatives I need to know that the first derivative exists not just at $x_0$ but in some neighborhood of $x_0,$ which seems implausible to exist given only this very local information.

Comment: See [What does it mean for a polynomial to be the 'best' approximation of a function around a point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3841575/13130) There is also the notion of the [Peano derivative](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Peano_derivative) (see also [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Peano+derivative%22&filter=0) and [this google scholar search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Peano+derivative%22)), which incidentally was what my Ph.D. supervisor's Ph.D. research dealt with.

Comment: For those interested, a comprehensive survey of Peano and other higher order differentiation notions was published a few years ago: Satya Narayan Mukhopadhyay, [**Higher Order Derivatives**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1439880476), Monographs and Surveys in Pure and Applied Mathematics #144, Chapman and Hall / CRC Press, 2012, xvi + 204 pages. An earlier survey paper, restricted to Peano derivatives and written by my supervisor and his supervisor, is: Evans/Weil, [*Peano derivatives: a survey*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/44153382), **Real Analysis Exchange** 7 #1 (1981-82), pp. 5-23.

Comment: Michael Barz' answer shows that this definition is not equivalent to the usual definition of higher order differentiability. But if you want to, you can view it as a perfectly sensible *generalization* of higher order differentiability. After all, for $n=1$, the two actually are equivalent. What's also interesting is that in the usually studied settings (*continuous* higher order differentiability on *open domains*), the two are again equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'd want to ask your function to be continuous at $x_0$ since otherwise you could get trivial counterexamples. But even asking for continuity at $x_0$ you can get into trouble.

Define $f$ from $[-1, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as follows. If $x \in \mathbb{Q},$ simply set $f(x) = x.$

If $x \in [-1, -1/2] \cup [1/2, 1],$ and $x$ is irrational, then define $f(x) = x/2.$

If $x$ is irrational and $x \in [-1/2, -1/3] \cup [1/3, 1/2],$ then define $f(x) = 2x/3.$

Continue on in this way, so that if $x$ is irrational and $x \in [-1/n, -1/(n+1)] \cup [1/(n+1), 1/n],$ then $f(x) = nx/(n+1).$

Now set $g(x) = f(x)\cdot x.$

We claim that $g$ is differentiable at 0 but nowhere else. It is clearly differentiable at 0, with derivative 0, since $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ (just write out the difference quotient to see why the implication holds; it is easy to see that $f$ is continuous at $0$). It is not differentiable anywhere else, though, since at any point $x_0 \neq 0,$ you can see that it looks locally like $x^2$ on the rational numbers, and so should have derivative $2x_0,$ but looks locally something like $nx^2/(n+1)$ on some irrational numbers, and so should have derivative $2nx_0/(n+1)$. These two only coincide if $x_0 = 0,$ and so you can't be differentiable at $x_0 \neq 0.$

Now we argue that $g$ has a second order Taylor polynomial at 0, namely $x^2.$

The idea is that in $[-1/n, 1/n],$ then either $g(x) - x^2$ equals $x^2 - x^2 = 0$ if $x\in\mathbb{Q},$ or else

$$\frac{n}{n+1}x^2 \leq g(x) \leq x^2,$$

so that $g(x) - x^2$ is bounded by $x^2/(n+1),$ so that $(g(x)-x^2)/x^2$ is bounded above by $1/(n+1)$ in $[-1/n, 1/n].$ It's clear now that the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(x)-x^2}{x^2} = 0.$

Comment: another example of existence of an approximating polynomial but the function not being sufficiently differentiable is $f(x)=x^{n+1}\cdot \chi_{\Bbb{Q}}(x)$, say for $n\geq 2$. In this case, $f$ is differentiable at the origin and nowhere else, but the zero polynomial is a good approximation (to order $n$): $f(0+h)=0+o(|h|^n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your example. But otherwise there seems to be no issue in defining a Taylor polynomial in this way. But do I really need to assume continuity at $x_0$? I can just pick a sequence $(x_n)$ which converges to $x_0$. $p_k (x_n)$ will converge to $f(x_0)$ and $r_k(x_n)$ converges to $0$ which proves continuity by my definition, or am I mistaken?